# TFS + Git newly initialized repository bare?

Tags: git, tfs, initialization, git-bare

In order to make a good start using Git with Microsoft TFS after migrating a project from SVN, I want to be sure that the remote/shared repository in TFS + Git is set up as good as possible. I work on the project alone at the moment, but I want the repository to be rugged enough for shared use and, frankly, my inexperienced hands.
I had already created a repository and pushed all the code into it, but then I read about the need to make shared repositories bare in order to prevent irreversible damage to the repository, in this case, by possible donkey moves on my side.

**The point:**
Enough of that ramble. The point now is that I would like to know for sure that my Git repository that I created in TFS is bare to start with, so that I can push my local bare into it.
That raises two questions for me:
 - Are the Git repositories initialized by TFS bare? 
 - Is there any way to check whether a remote TFS + Git repository is bare?

*Note:
I have limited access to TFS meaning no SSH/direct command line access to the TFS machine.*

Comment: Do you mean "empty" when you say "bare"?  A "bare" repository is one with no working directory, which may (or may not) be empty and have no commits.  They're two very different concepts.

Comment: @Edward Thomson By bare I don't mean empty. I mean a repository without a working directory, like you suggested. I want my (filled with source files) remote/shared repository to be bare as it is described as best practice in many places.
My initial situation would be a local bare repository with my source code in it.

Before I start pushing my local repository into the remote, the remote would need to be bare (AND empty) in the first place, I would say.

For that I would like to be sure that the TFS + Git repository I made is bare. Hence the initial questions.

Answer (score 0):

Git repositories created in TFS are empty (bare) at the time that they are created.

You can check by using the "code" tab in Web Access and looking at the repo. It should state that it is empty.

For one you have already pushed code into you can view the history in the same code tab and see your commit is the first.

Comment: You're making a big assumption that people are using TFS on the cloud rather than a TFS server running on a local network. Your answer doesn't help users running TFS on their own server.